# Socket.io and Angular 2

Tags: sockets, angular

I'm trying to use `Socket.io-client` library in Angular 2 app.

There are tons of different guides related to fast changes that Angular 2 have in a past couple of months.

I don't know do I doing something wrong.

What I did?

```
npm install socket.io-client --save
```

After that in component:

```
...

import * as io from "socket.io-client";
...

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

constructor() {

    this.socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4200");
    this.socket.on("connection", () => console.log("this is onl a test"));

  }
}

}
```

When I open console I see following errors:

```
  GET http://localhost:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LdBXte5 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: This might be silly, but you do have your socket server running on that port right?

Comment: ... exactly! It was wrong port at io.connect("http://localhost:4200") I have to use 3001 because my server in local running on that port. 

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add the answer as completed to help to another one?